# "Message: unknown error: cannot focus element" in python selenium driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Why does this piece of code throw an exception `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element`?

As far as I can tell, I'm choosing the right element. Googling suggested to have a `.click()` on element before sending keys but that didn't help either.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/")
login_wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

assert "Welcome to HDFC Bank" in driver.title

frame = login_wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'login_page')))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

try:
    elem = login_wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pwd_field')))
    print("Page is ready!")
    elem.send_keys("123456")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because what element you've located by the `pwd_field` class name - you've actually got a `span` element matching the locator. Instead, you meant to get to the password `input` element:

```
elem = login_wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'input_password')))
```